# Format code in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I just started playing with Dart in Dart Editor.

Since Dart Editor is a distribution of Eclipse, I figured that to format my code, all I'd need to do is press ***crtl + shift + f***.  However, when I did this, it brought up the "find/replace" window instead.  I tried seeing if there were any options in "preferences" to fix this, but I found none.  (The preferences seem a bit bare-bones at this point.)

So, is there a short-cut key for formatting code?  And if there is, why is it not ***crtl + shift + f*** like it is in other distributions of Eclipse?

Comment: As for why not ctrl + shift + f for format, I think it's a matter of preference. Eclipse doesn't have a binding for search, and I wish it did. So the fact that search has a binding in the Dart Editor is nice. They aren't just trying to replicate Eclipse; they're trying to do something better. Whether this hits the mark is a matter of preference.

Comment: I've noticed that there are two bindings for search.  Ctrl + Shift + f brings up the search/replace box, while Ctrl + f brings up a small search bar at the bottom of the window.  I wonder, can I change the bindings?  But I guess that's a separate question.

Comment: @CorayThan Eclipse does have a search (Ctrl + F) and a more advanced search (Ctrl + H)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

With Dart 1.2, released 2/26, you can format code through the Source menu, although the source menu doesn't exist in some situations and I'm not sure why. You can also use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> by default. To modify what the short cut is, you can go to Tools --> Preferences --> Key Bindings --> Export to File. Then search in the file for "Format" and modify the correct key binding, then reimport it.

Old answer:

The autoformat function for Dart code in the Dart Editor has not been introduced yet. From what I've read in the [Dart formatter issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2059) on the Dart issue tracker, it sounds like it should be introduced in version 1.2 of the Dart Editor, which hopefully won't be too long from now.

I actually did see it and use it for a few days (I think they rolled back 1.2), but there was still no keyboard shortcut for it. It was an option you needed to manually click. (Hopefully you can bind it yourself to a shortcut.)